# How do I select all child rows corresponding to a set of parent ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I select all child rows corresponding to a certain parent table using ActiveRecord queries.

```
create table foo (id, ...)
create table bar (id, foo_id, ...)

select * from foo where key = ? 
# The above return a single row or multiple rows.

select * from bar where foo_id in <ids from the above output>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only queries with `ActiveRecord`

```
foo = Foo.where(:key = ?)
Bar.where(:foo_id => foo)
```

Using associations and [eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) :

```
#foo model
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

#bar model
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :foo
end

#query
Foo.includes(:bars).where(:key => ?).collect(&:bars)
```

Comment: Your query returns instances of foo, not bar. According to the last query stated in the question, it specifically says "select * from bar...".

Comment: I am assuming the query will return a collection of Bar(s) here

Comment: If you strictly just want `bars` you can collect them from the previous query I will update the answer.

Comment: You don't need eager loading - you can load Bar directly and join the foos

Answer (score 0):

Humm... I don't know if your question is whether something like that can be done with ARel or not (which, it cannot). What you want is to provide matches using a sub-query, which you can do in SQL, and therefore using ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql("select * from bar where foo_id in 
(select id from foo where key = #{key})")
```

Comment: in rails 3.x (or at least 3.2) you can do subselects with arel.

Answer (score 0):

Arel *will* do this:

```
Profile.where(user_id: User.select("id").where(exclude_from_analytics: true))
#=> Profile Load (395.1ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` IN (SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`exclude_from_analytics` = 1)
```

Whether you actually want to do a subselect is another thing - its worth trying to write the query as a join:

```
Bar.joins(:foo).where(:foos => {:key => key})
```

assuming that you have setup Bar with a `belongs_to :foo` association. The joins method will also accept a raw sql fragment

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
Bar.find_all_by_foo_id([1,2,3,4])
```

In which case you will have to find all the foo ids previously.  But if you need it in one query sub-query which ChuckE mentioned is best.